# Return different result in leetcode vs colab using same code

Tags: python, variables, matrix

I write this code in colab trying to rotate a matrix by 90 degree:

```
matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
N = len(matrix)
new = [row[:] for row in matrix]
for i in range(N):
    for j in  range(N-1,-1,-1):
        new[i][N-j-1]=matrix[j][i]
matrix = new
print(matrix)
```

It gives me [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]] which is correct.

While I use the same code in leetcode, it doesn't work. What's different in leetcode is that I write the code in a function and it shows the matrix hasn't changed.

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, matrix):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify matrix in-place instead.
        """
        N = len(matrix)
        new = [row[:] for row in matrix]

        for i in range(N):
            for j in  range(N-1,-1,-1):
                new[i][N-j-1]=matrix[j][i]
        matrix = new
```

And it gives me [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

I think the problem is about I am not really assigning the new to matrix something like that. I am still confused about it. Can you please explain it to me? :)

Comment: The short answer is that parameters are passed by value  in python.  If you want to return the value of the new matrix, return new.  If you want to return a new value of matrix, you can't just assign it to new.  But you can copy the values from new into matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the value from your rotate function:

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, matrix):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify matrix in-place instead.
        """
        N = len(matrix)
        new = [row[:] for row in matrix]

        for i in range(N):
            for j in  range(N-1,-1,-1):
                new[i][N-j-1]=matrix[j][i]
        return new

s = Solution()
matrix = s.rotate(matrix)
```

Well, that said, it looks like you want to just manipulate matrix in place (from the comment in your code).  If you'd like to do that, your rotate() function has to copy its values to the matrix variable (basically a deep copy).

Here's a second version where we do an in-place copy into matrix:

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, matrix):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify matrix in-place instead.
        """
        N = len(matrix)
        new = [row[:] for row in matrix]

        for i in range(N):
            for j in  range(N-1,-1,-1):
                new[i][N-j-1]=matrix[j][i]

        for r,row in enumerate(new):
          for c,col in enumerate(row):
            matrix[r][c] = new[r][c]
    

matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(matrix)
s = Solution()
s.rotate(matrix)
print(matrix)
```

And here's the results:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```